# Accessing an additional map view from Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I created an additional map view (in addition to the main canvas). How can I access this map view from Python to modify e. g. the extent?

There is no code to show as I am completely missing the initial entry point. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this is what you want (though I think it is).

You can access all map canvases open in the app via the [mapCanvases()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a16c14a23c86b8d819268d5b95a148740) method of the `iface` object. You can identify canvases by their `objectName()` (the main canvas is 'theMapCanvas', additional map view canvas is 'Map 1' etc).

For example:

```py
for canvas in iface.mapCanvases():
    print(canvas.objectName())
    if canvas.objectName() == 'Map 1':
        canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: @bugmenot123, great! No problem :-)